# SaveAs to any Desktop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save an Excel file to any user's desktop.

Filename format: DTR then the Date today

I get an error.

```vb
Sub saveAs()
    Sheets("DTR").Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        .SaveAs Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & _
          "\DTR" & Date & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook _
          , CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: btw the part where the DATE code was the error being pointed out, but when i take off the date the code goes well. but i need the date after the DTR name

Comment: "\DTR" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"